# Why is Android System.currentTimeMillis() not an accurate Timestamp?

Tags: java, android, time, system, unix-timestamp

I've encountered what appears to be a very unusual bug while developing an android application.

The following code in my MainActivity `onCreate` method:

```
long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(ts);
```

The returned value is `1570469720537`.

This time would be in the year 51736 according to [unixtimestamp.com](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

Has anybody encountered this problem? Any ideas what may be causing it?

Comment: That is the time in milliseconds, not epoch time in seconds.

Comment: If you want a Unix timestamp, that is, the time in seconds since the epoch, the easiest and most direct way is `Instant.now().getEpochSecond()`. It also very clear about whether you get seconds or milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While epoch time is measured in seconds, [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) returns the time in milliseconds for more accuracy, which is the value you see in the example. If you divide it by 1000 you will get the time in seconds, which will convert to the current epoch time you expect.

You can paste the value in here to see the timestamp: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: "Note that generally speaking all timestamps in Java are measured in milliseconds." Except for the ones in `java.time`, which have nanosecond precision.

Comment: @OleV.V. it is a backwards way to put it. I was attempting (unsuccessfully, clearly) to imply that there are lots of timestamps that aren't millisecond precision, so the statement is simply false.

Comment: I’ll take the comment by @AndyTurner (that I didn’t read in its proper context at first, sorry) a step further. To me all timestamps in Java have nanosecond precision. Except (most of) the legacy ones that we shouldn’t concern ourselves with anymore, so we can practically ignore the exception.