# Java OffsetDateTime showing strange year value

Tags: java, datetime, datetimeoffset

Per the IntelliJ debugger, the OffsetDateTime value is showing like:

+51434-04-02T15:28:41Z

Any idea how to parse the year part or make sense of it? The raw date is actually in milliseconds when I view it on the DB. I have no access to the team that is saving these dates. Also, when accessing the data via my tests it's showing the same when I do a log.debug.

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html

Comment: What's the date in milliseconds that caused this string to be produced?

Comment: Not what produced what's above but here's a ms example: 1559909381182

Comment: Fixed this issue: it had to do with Jackson deserialization of the OffsetDateTime property within my domain model object that gets created after a Feign rest call. To fix this I added the Jackson property to my application.yml: jackson.deserialization.read-date-timestamps-as-nanoseconds: false, jackson.deserialization.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone: false

Comment: Related: (1) [Incorrect Timestamp Value - c.getTimeInMills()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911688/incorrect-timestamp-value-c-gettimeinmills) (2) [Why is Android System.currentTimeMillis() not an accurate Timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58274641/why-is-android-system-currenttimemillis-not-an-accurate-timestamp)

Answer (score 3):

Seeing the timestamp, I think I know why this is happening. Some part of the code has incorrectly interpreted the timestamp 1559909381182. This timestamp represents a the number of milliseconds since the epoch, but your code has interpreted it as a number of *seconds*. Compare these two lines:

```
System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1559909381182L));
System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1559909381182L));
```

The first will print out a date thousands of years in the future, while the second line will print a more reasonable date.

You should try and find where you have interpreted it as a second.