# Time conversion from seconds to date issue

Tags: java, date, kotlin, time

I have the following `Long` variable holding epoch value in seconds, which I'm trying to convert into a `Date`.

```
val seconds = 1341855763000
val date = Date(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds))
```

The output is way off than I expected. Where did I go wrong?

```
Actual: Wed Sep 19 05:26:40 GMT+05:30 44491
Expected: Monday July 9 11:12:43 GMT+05:30 2012
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java OffsetDateTime showing strange year value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287533/java-offsetdatetime-showing-strange-year-value)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use an appropriate calss from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Start by looking at the `Instant` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The output is way off than I expected. Where did I go wrong?

```
Actual: Wed Sep 19 05:26:40 GMT+05:30 44491
Expected: Monday July 9 11:12:43 GMT+05:30 2012
```

The value is already in `milliseconds` and by using `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds)` you are wrongly multiplying it by `1000`.

### By using the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html):

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1341855763000L);
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2012-07-09T17:42:43Z
```

### By using legacy `java.util.Date`:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Date(1341855763000L));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Mon Jul 09 18:42:43 BST 2012
```

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (package, `java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Interesting, why is there a 1 hour difference?

Comment: It's because I'm in the UK (British Summer Time) and `java.util.Date` uses the default time-zone. That's why it is wiser to use the modern date-time API (e.g. `java.time.Instant`) where you have immense possibilities to handle and present not only date and time but also time-zone information.

Comment: Good to know! Let me explore the `java.time` package

Answer (score 6):

The value you have is not in seconds but in milliseconds. Remove the "seconds to millis" conversion.

```
val milliSeconds = 1341855763000
val date = Date(milliSeconds)
```

Comment: I went way ahead into future!

Answer (score 4):

Your value : 1341855763000 is not in seconds, it is in milliseconds.
The current timestamp is :
new Date().getTime() =>
1598612990351
Same number of digits than :
1341855763000

If you multiply 1341855763000 by 1000 (as you say), it gives the year :
44491 after JC :D
Have a good day

Answer (score 3):

I think your time is actually in milliseconds. If I convert `1341855763000` using this [website](https://www.epochconverter.com/) it gives me your expected time and this as well:

```
fun main() {
  val millis = 1341855763000
  val date = Date(millis)
  println(date)
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use seconds:

```
fun main() {
  val seconds = 1341855763L
  val date = Date(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds))
  println(date)
}
```

Just divide by `1000`.